Kernel panic error
I am getting the error below. I can boot into the older kernel but am unable to do so into the newer one. I have a loaded server with information on it that I cannot lose, so I am hoping that someone can help me with a step-by-step guide on how to fix this.
Software being run is:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel Linux 5.15.0.122-generic (but the version .124 is the one with the problem 122 is the one that is working)
kernel error:


Boot into the older kernel and run sudo apt update followed by sudo apt full-upgrade. Reboot. Does it fix the issue?

ADDED more info above to OS release and Kernel info. So do I do the sudo update or the boot into LIVE. What one is least likely to muck up the server to the point that it will not boot at all?

If you're running Ubuntu 22.04.1 then I hope you keep the system offline, as that would show you've not applied upgrades and security fixes in a very long time (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.2, but installed systems upgraded BEFORE that date). If your 22.04.1 came from uname that only shows packaging details related to kernel and not what you're running. A fully upgraded 22.04 system currently reports as 22.04.5 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/)
